# Get Local Folders from App WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm having an issue trying to save a file into a folder of the WinRT app I'm working at. More specific : I can't manage to retrieve the folder. I need to save some files and afterwards to retrieve them from that same folder, let's say `MyFolder` which is actually at the same level in the app with the `Assets` folder. How can I achieve such thing?

So far I tried

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder")
```

and

```
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
```

and both seem to tell me that such folder doesn't exist. Now, I can't seem to figure it out if I'm on the right track or it's something foolish I've done and causes that exception. I can't really post the whole code, because it's actually a call to a larger method with other calls, and so on.

Also, I'd like to know (if any of these methods are correct), if the app gets an update, the content is affected in any way (better said, lost).

Thank you.

Comment: See [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx).

Comment: Looked over, looked over the the samples and still didn't come to a solution. But I came across this blog post of @Jerry Nixon, http://stackoverflow.com/users/265706/jerry-nixon-msft , according to which, my first method posted is correct. I can get the Assets folder but I can't retrieve any other...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) will give you the 'file system' defined by the application package, so you'd see you the commonly used Asset folder, for instance, via the URI  `ms-appx:///Assets`  Anything accessed via InstalledLocation or the `ms-appx` scheme is read-only because it's defined by the project you deployed from Visual Studio.

[ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) allows you to access the 'file system' owned by the current application/user (and stored at `%AppData%/Local/Packages/<yourapppackage>/LocalState`). You can create whatever structure you want here to manage your various roles, and use the `ms-appdata:///local/DirLeve1/DirLeve2/File3` URI to access your files).  That storage is retained through updates to your application, though, of course, you'll need a strategy for updating whatever stored data formats are required to interact with the newer version of your application.

It sounds like you're assuming LocalFolder cannot contain a folder hiearachy; it can, and so you could have a Recents subfolder for instance under the LocalFolder reference and handle things that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started with wrong assumptions. My problem was, that I thought I could create the MyFolder to be like in the app (like default or something) and afterwards retrieve it with GetFolderAsync("MyFolder"), but there was no folder to get... So I create one when app is first launched and then the operation is omitted of the folder already exists, when the app is launched at other times. Also, thank you for the update-regarding information.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use the [`ms-appx` URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx).  Something like this:

```
await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///MyFolder");
```

Also, you need to make sure that the folder is actually getting included in the output.  I'm not exactly sure how you do this in C# projects -- in C++ it's by setting the folder/file's "Is Content" build property to true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I came across this form as well, but I was searching for the method in wrong namespaces... Eventually, I've decided of simply using ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. I didn't want to use LocalStorage directly and instead a custom folder, because I will have more items and when the app launches, I will need to show them all in a Recents section. This will make things harder if I would want to keep files with different roles in the same LocalFolder. I guess, I could have an escape route to filter them by extension...