# How to save image to azure mysql database using UWP

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, windows-10, uwp

I have captured picture using
cameracaptureui and I have the image in image control.
Now the problem is how to save this captured image to my database.?
normally i did this task in windows form via converting image to byets. but now bit confused in UWP.
thanks in advance

What I have tried:`

```
 private async void button_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create camera instance with camera capture ui 
        CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);
        StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (photo == null)
        {
            // User cancelled photo capture
            return;
        }
        //return the captured results to fram via bitmap
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap,BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);
        imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Image to `Base64` and save it to mysql database. Save Captured Image to `Application Local Folder` and Convert it to `Base64`.

C# code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

  private async void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + "your_image_name.png"));
        string base64image = await _encodeToBase64(file.Path);
    }

 public async Task<string> _encodeToBase64(string filePath)
    {
        string encode = String.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
            IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
            reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
            encode = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent);
        }
        return encode;
    }
```

Comment: in new uri what path I should provide.?

Comment: @SheikhMuhammadAmaan-Ullah this is your application local folder read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156706/get-local-folders-from-app-winrt).

Comment: save your captured image to Application  Local State  Folder.

Comment: what datatype should select in database.?