# Get App path for fopen() in UWP

Tags: c++, uwp

I am porting an existing C/C++ application to UWP that uses fopen()/fclose(). On Win32, I used to use the following two functions to get the path of app resources (read only), and to get the path of app storage (read/write):

```
char resourcePath[2048];
const char *GetResourcePath(void)
{
    GetCurrentDirectoryA(sizeof(resourcePath), resourcePath);
    strcat(resourcePath, "/");
    return resourcePath;
}

char storagePath[2048];
const char *GetStoragePath(void)
{
    GetCurrentDirectoryA(sizeof(storagePath), storagePath);
    strcat(storagePath, "/");
    return storagePath;
}
```

What are the UWP equivalents? I seem to be only able to find information in C#.
It appears I can "rb" fopen() files from this folder, but I cannot "wb". Why not? It's the application's folder, is it not?

Comment: What errors do you get on "WB" ? Idiomatic way is to use "Windows runtime API" for uwp, it is accessed from CPP via [modern](https://moderncpp.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Local Folders from App WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156706/get-local-folders-from-app-winrt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetCurrentDirectory works on UWP, but you must use the Unicode variant (GetCurrentDirectoryW instead of GetCurrentDirectoryA). However, I wouldn't use it to get the location where your application is installed, as it can be overwritten easily by using SetCurrentDirectory.

You can use [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224681) property, and then use [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.path) property on the returned StorageFolder, but if you use that, you will not be able to share code with your Win32 application.

What I suggest doing is instead retrieving the path of the executable by using GetModuleFileNameW, and then trimming the last path component to get the directory:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

std::wstring GetExecutablePath()
{
    std::wstring buffer;
    size_t nextBufferLength = MAX_PATH;

    for (;;)
    {
        buffer.resize(nextBufferLength);
        nextBufferLength *= 2;

        SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

        auto pathLength = GetModuleFileName(reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(&__ImageBase), &buffer[0], static_cast<DWORD>(buffer.length()));

        if (pathLength == 0)
            throw std::exception("GetModuleFileName failed"); // You can call GetLastError() to get more info here

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            buffer.resize(pathLength);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}

void RemoveLastPathComponent(std::wstring& path)
{
    auto directoryLength = path.length() - 1;

    while (directoryLength > 0 && path[directoryLength] != '\\' && path[directoryLength] != '/')
        directoryLength--;

    if (directoryLength > 0)
        path.resize(directoryLength);
}

std::wstring GetExecutableDirectory()
{
    auto executablePath = GetExecutablePath();
    RemoveLastPathComponent(executablePath);
    return executablePath;
}
```

Also worth noting: don't use fopen. If the user has non-english characters in their user name that are not representable in the current code page, your code will fail. Use _wfopen or CreateFile2 instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is /most/ of my answer, but not about the local WRITE storage location, which would be:

Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ localFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed the read/write path. LocalFolder is indeed the right place for that, and there's no other way (that's compatible with win32 path) available.

Comment: I would stick to using `Package.InstallLocation` rather than doing the tricks above, since you need to get the data directory anyway (which is UWP-specific).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT apparently Package.InstallLocation is broken with optional packages. If you're distributing your code in a DLL, it could be placed in an optional package along with the rest of its dependent files. In this case, `Package.InstallLocation` will fail, while using GetModuleFileNameW still works.

Comment: It will also break if you're trying to load resources that are localized into different packages. What kind of files are you trying to read?

Comment: Just lose files that are distributed with my library (in their own custom format). I actually had a complaint about it not working with optional packages, and had to go change my library to use GetModuleFileNameW instead.